# Javascript equivalent of vbscript setlocale

Tags: javascript, localization, vbscript, setlocale

Hopefully a quick answer for someone, but my google-fu has deserted me.

In vbscript I can use "setlocale" to set the locale a script is running in. I need a javascript version.

So for example, say my user is using a browser with french settings, but I want numbers and dates to be in english and worked with as if they are english. Then in vbscript I could do

```
setlocale 2057
```

to set to english locale

and then when I'm finished working with the numbers/ dates I can set back to french

```
setlocale 1036
```

Is there a javascript equivalent? How can I accomplish this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to choose locales in JavaScript.

However, doing stuff in the US English locale is not generally a problem since that's what JavaScript does anyway. If you handle `Number`​s with parseInt, toString and so on you will always be dealing with `.` for decimal points and there will be no thousands-separator. `Date` default formatting also uses English weekday and month names, and a browser-specific date format that ignores what your locale's default would be.

You have to go out of your way to get anything locale-specific in JavaScript, with methods like `toLocaleString`. The results are typically poor and inconsistent across browsers. If you want reliable localisation in your webapps, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked the question without testing the problem properly first- now I have and it matches what you are saying- so I don't have to worry about it which is perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, JavaScript does not offer similar locale features. You have some locale-aware functions for specific tasks. For instance, you can sort a string with [localeCompare()](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference#quickIDX22), you can uppercase it with [toLocaleUpperCase()](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Strings_Reference#quickIDX35) and you can print a date with toLocaleString(). And you don't specify a locale, they work with whatever language settings the interpreter thinks appropriate. And, of course, it all depends on having these functions available in all target browsers.

You can download the [official specs](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php) at the ECMAScript site and have a look at the [Mozilla implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) (the IE implementation is probably somewhere in the MSDN site).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided to select the other answer as the correct one as it was more definitive- but if I could select this as correct also I would- sorry about that